# How can I log into my web app, then read through the records of my data.json file using TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've googled and I can find how to loop through my data file.  Apparently you run a test for each record of data.

I would like to have my single test log in, then cycle through each 'record' or item of the data file.  The data is a series of searches in our app.  So, the test would login and assert logged in then run those searches...

```
test('searches', async t => {
await t
    // Log in...   
    .typeText('input[id="login-name"]', 'aguy')
    .typeText('input[id="login-password"]', 'bbb')
    .click('button[id="signin-button"')
    .expect(Selector('span[id="logged-in-user"]').innerText).contains('Hal')  

    // At this point the app is ready to run through the searches doing this...
    // forEach item in my data...
        .typeText('input[id="simplecriteria"]', data.criteria)
        .click('button[class="search-button"]')
        .expect(Selector('div[class="mat-paginator-range-label"]').innerText).contains(data.srchResult)      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe has [test hooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/organize-tests.html#test-hooks), I recommend using them even though they are not that usuful in your case because TestCafe deletes cookies between tests, so if you log in once and then write your test like so:

```js
const testData = require('../Resources/testData.json');

let executed = false;
fixture `Searches`    
    .page(baseUrl)    
    .beforeEach(async t => {       

        if (!executed) {
            // run this only once before all tests
            executed = true;       

            // log in        
            await t 
                .typeText('input[id="login-name"]', 'aguy')
                .typeText('input[id="login-password"]', 'bbb')
                .click('button[id="signin-button"')
                .expect(Selector('span[id="logged-in-user"]').innerText).contains('Hal');
        }               
    });

testData.forEach((data) => {
    test('Searches', async t => {
        await t
            .typeText('input[id="simplecriteria"]', data.criteria)
            .click('button[class="search-button"]')
            .expect(Selector('div[class="mat-paginator-range-label"]').innerText).contains(data.srchResult);
    });
});
```

then you'll most likely be logged out after the first test.

However, I'd still use `beforeEach` hook, but put the loop inside the test:

```js
const testData = require('../Resources/testData.json');

fixture `Searches`    
    .page(baseUrl)
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t
            // Log in...   
            .typeText('input[id="login-name"]', 'aguy')
            .typeText('input[id="login-password"]', 'bbb')
            .click('button[id="signin-button"')
            .expect(Selector('span[id="logged-in-user"]').innerText).contains('Hal');
    });

test('Searches', async t => {
    testData.forEach((data) => {
        await t
            .typeText('input[id="simplecriteria"]', data.criteria)
            .click('button[class="search-button"]')
            .expect(Selector('div[class="mat-paginator-range-label"]').innerText).contains(data.srchResult);
    });          
});
```

There's obvious disadvantag:

- many different searches are added as one test, so if one fails, the whole "searches" test case will be marked as failed

Another solution might be to find out what it means to be logged in. If it's about adding some cookie, you might log in once and then only set up the cookie before your tests. However, in many modern systems, such "log-in cookies" will have `httpOnly` flag, so you can't really set it in JavaScript.

Comment: Just so I understand, as written, there will be a logout with each test and a new login is required between each search.  Maybe if a understand what it means to be logged in/cookie I can find a better way.  I'm moving away from Selenium, hopefully as it has been flaky for us.  In the selenium test, we were able to log in, cycle through the searches then log out.  I'm really not concerned with failure if only one of the searches fail as all are supposed to pass.  I guess I'm inquiring into the possibility of logging in, doing all the searches as part of a single test, then logging out.

Comment: When I tried your solution, we have a pop up that indicates the user is already logged in.  The way I worked around it is used .afterEach and logged out after each search.  It gets the job done so I guess I'm OK.  It would be nice to be able to do multiple searches in a single test though, with login before and logout after all searches complete.  If one fails here, that is OK and desireable.

Comment: Such a popup might be created in a way that after closing it, you'll get a cookie with no httpOnly flag. If so, I'd set this cookie so I don't ever need to close it with a click. Closing this very popup is not what you're testing here in this test, so try to avoid it and save some time.